# How can I enter multiple Unicode strings (including right-to-lesft reading order) in Java source file?

Tags: java, unicode

I am testing a piece of Java code and need to create an array of strings. These strings are words in different languages, including those like Arabic with the right-to-left reading order (don't know if that matters...)

So I need to do something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> words = ...
words.add(<word-in-english>);
words.add(<word-in-chinese>);
words.add(<word-in-russian>);
words.add(<word-in-arabic>);
```

What's the best way to put these into my Java code? Is there a way to do it other than using "\u" escape for every character in a string? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. You can use statements like 'String word = "Добрый день"' in Java without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for it to work you must do these 2 things:

- Save the source file in Unicode format (UTF-8). How to do this is IDE/Text Editor dependent.
- Compile the file by specifying the UTF-8 charset. Like this:

`javac -encoding utf-8 MyFile.java`

Comment: I saved my file as UTF8 in Eclipse but I did not specify encoding while compiling, at least not explicitly (does Eclipse do it automatically if any file in a project gets saved as UTF8?). My code seems to be working correctly. How critical is "-encoding utf-8 "?

Comment: @IZ it's very important if you compile the code at the command line. There, everything must be explicit (include debugging code or not, classpath or not, charset etc.). Eclipse probably specifies it for you, that's why it worked. I'm not that familiar with Eclipse (yet !), I usually use Netbeans (got used to it). But you can probably find these settings in the project's properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the encoding of editor/IDE to UTF-8, and java compiler too. For international projects this begins to become more and more a convention.

Unfortunately you would need to set your IDE font to a full unicode font which might be 35 MB or such. Or use for a missing chinese "\uXXXX" escaping, using `native2ascii`.

Depending on your sources, you might use files per language.

Comment: As far as I know modern systems don't need a single font with all the characters. Instead, if a character does not appear in a specified font then a fall-back font will be used to display those character that need it. The only requirement is that there has to be some font installed on the system that has that character. Otherwise there's a font named 'Last Resort' which contains glyphs for all characters, but it's only a generic glyph that tells you what Unicode block the character is from, so this is used if you don't have any appropriate fonts installed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no problem to put any Unicode characters into your java code including RTL languages. It a little bit depends on your IDE but I believe that all modern IDEs support RTL typing. At least Eclipse does.

You have to save your source code using `UTF-8` charset. Again it depends on your IDE. I eclipse right-click on file, then choose resource and change its encoding to UTF-8.

Sometimes it is just not convenient to type RTL texts in IDE. In this case type text using other program (MS Word, Notepad etc) and then copy and paste it into java code.

BTW think about storing unicode strings in separate resouce file. It is usually more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't something like this work:

```
BufferedReader bufReader =
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file_name), "UTF-16"));
```

Pay attention to *UTF-16* .

Comment: I am not trying to ingest the strings ffom file, I am trying to hardcode the strings inside my source.